# Boost thread interrupted when qt crashes

Tags: qt, boost-thread

I have a qt application with a few boost threads running. When I get an unhandled exception (ex. std::runtime_error) in one of my qt event handlers, the boost threads also catch thread_interrupted exceptions.

Why does this happen? I already have try catch blocks around all of the interruption points, like boost sleep, so I can't figure out where the thread_interrupted exception comes from (the exception is caught in the thread function even though all the calls documented as interruption points are already wrapped in try-catch blocks).

Does the runtime or qt somehow terminate the boost threads and cause the thread_interrupted exception?

Ideally, I would like any unhandled exception in qt to present in the main thread and not in the boost threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I found an unprotected wait on a barrier.
When an exception occurs in a Qt slot Qt starts cleaning up and the application destructor is called. This in turn caused my threads to be interrupted and those threads waiting on barriers then threw exceptions.